# How can I show My Computer icon on the Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I want `My computer` shortcut on my desktop in Windows 7,  like how it is present in Windows XP. What should I do to have these icons on my desktop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click desktop -> Personalization -> Change Desktop icons. Select the icons you want to be seen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Windows logo/flag [usually at the bottom left of the screen] then find 'Computer'

Right click on 'Computer' and select 'Show on Desktop'

'Show on Desktop' should now have a tick beside it. Go to your desktop and you should see an item labelled 'Computer'